# Duda array en ensamblador

Tags: array, ensamblador

estoy con una duda en un array, estoy aprendiendo sobre ello con qtspim.

```
.data 
array: .word 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 
.text 
.globl main
main:
li $t0,3 
li $t1,4 
mul $t2,$t1,$t0 
lw $a0,array($t2) 
li $v0,1 
syscall
```

¿Por que al multiplica t1 por t0 y guardar en t2 y usarlo para el indice del array **me imprime 44**?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Luís Filipe. Estás usando QtSpim como compilador para el lenguaje ensamblador, pero no especificas qué assembler estás usando en específico. Si no me equivoco, por la sintaxis, ¿es leguaje ensamblador MIPS?. En caso de ser así, podrías especificarme si el repertorio de instrucciones, se corresponde con el MIPS r2000 o r3000. De igual modo, si puede mencionar el propósito del ejercicio, es decir, lo que pretendes conseguir con él (Si tienes algún enunciado de algún ejercicio). Saludos

Comment: array es un arreglo de words, y cada word tiene 4 bytes de tamaño. Al hacer x * 4, calculas el offset en bytes para el (x+1)avo elemento (posicion x) del arreglo.

Comment: Hola @LearningDeveloper es MIPS pero no sé la si es r2000 o 3000. Pero mi propósito es comprender el uso del indice, porque la multiplicación me esta dejando en la duda.

Comment: @braver, así que en un array de word yo tengo que hacer la multiplicación x*4 siempre, siendo x el indice. Usando  el t1 para calcular el offset así voy a la posicion 3 del array que es t0, ¿cierto?

Comment: @LuísFilipe sí, eso mismo